# SSH - Connect & Execute : "echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'"

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, terminal, escaping

Here's my bash (shell?) script.

```
command="ssh root@$ip";
command2="\"ls /;bash\"";
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$command $command2; bash"
```

connects to the server and executes the command of

```
 ls /
```

works just fine.

But instead of  **`ls /`**..
I want to execute this command:

```
 echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'
```

I replaced " **`ls /`** " with the code above, but soon as it connects,
it simply prints a blank line.

Based on my understanding, the code is being executed locally before it reaches the server because stuff is not escaped.

If I manually paste this code on my remote server..

```
   echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'
```

it works just fine. Prints out exactly what it should be printing out.

So the question is: where do the backslashes go in my code ?

I know it sounds like simply trying bunch of backslashes..
until something works.

I tried many ways. I even tried triple and sixtuple backslashes to escape things.

**Update**

This is not sufficient.
It still only prints out a blank line soon as it connects.

```
command="ssh root@$ip";
command2="\"echo \$SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print \$1}';bash\"";
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$command $command2; bash"
```

**Update 2**

from one of the answers..

code below works okay but it looks "un-light" to my eyes or maybe just my mind because I am not used to exec and right to left piping ?

```
command="ssh -t root@$ip";
command2="\"awk '{ print \\\$1 }' <<< \\\$SSH_CONNECTION; exec \\\$SHELL\""
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$command $command2; bash"
```

**Update 3**

from the answers..

```
command2='"echo \"\$SSH_CONNECTION\" | awk '"'"'{ print \$1 }'"'"'; exec \$SHELL"'
```

also seems to be working okay.

although info is being given as "exec" being less resource consuming.. i am still looking for a solution without the "exec" command because "exec" command reminds me of "php" which is not light stuff.. so maybe it is just perception

**Update 4:**

Turns out "exec \$SHELL" was not part of the code. it was simply a replacement for the "bash" command to stay logged in in ssh.

Although info is being said it is less resource consuming than the bash
command.. it is to be studied in the future.

for now this seems to be the final result.

```
command2='"echo \"\$SSH_CONNECTION\" | awk '"'"'{ print \$1 }'"'"';bash"'
```

it looks very reasonable simply piping from left to right..

**Update 5**

The final code is:

```
command="ssh -p 2201 -t root@$ip";
command2='"echo \"\$SSH_CONNECTION\" | awk '"'"'{ print \$1 }'"'"';bash"'
xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$command $command2; bash"
```

Comment: You may want to try using single quotes instead, that will make sure the env. var doesnt get evaluated locally (you'll have to change your awk arg to use double quotes then): command='echo $SSH_CONNECTION'

Comment: some progress:  `command2="\"{ echo 'aaaa'; } | tail -c 2;bash\""; `

Comment: You can do the same without `exec`, but "just because I don't like it" isn't a good reason not to use it.

Comment: Or you could just look up what `exec` does. If you want to avoid your "blood boiling", just don't use it and live with an extra process.

Comment: oooh "exec"  being used for replacement to "bash" command. i see. it does not have to be there.

Comment: I have removed your last paragraph. Don't add it again. It also looks like your plan was to delete your question after you got an answer - don't do that, or you're very well underway to actually live up to your user name, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape twice: once for SSH, once for the shell command you give to `xfce4-terminal`. I've tested this with `xterm` instead of `xfec4-terminal`, but it should be the same:

```
$ cmd1='ssh -t root@as'
$ cmd2="\"awk '{ print \\\$1 }' <<< \\\"\\\$SSH_CONNECTION\\\"; exec \\\$SHELL\""
$ xfce4-terminal -x sh -c "$cmd1 $cmd2"
```

I've added `-t` to allocate a pseudo-terminal, and I use a here-string instead of `echo` and a pipe.

Instead of spawning Bash in a subshell, I'm using `exec $SHELL`.

An alternative to triple backslashes in `cmd2` is to single-quote it, but to get a single quote into a single-quoted string, you have to use the unwieldy `'"'"'`:

```
cmd2='"awk '"'"'{ print \$1 }'"'"' <<< \"\$SSH_CONNECTION\"; exec \$SHELL"'
```

Comment: works okay. but i have never before used "exec" command in shell before. only in php. i hope this is not a "heavy" ( resource consuming ) ..  design (method ) ? "exec" part and tripple <'s kind of makes one wonder if this is taking the "heavy" route.. also things are from right to left.. rather than left to the right.. like "piping" stuff. totally alien (to me) method but works.

Comment: `exec bash` is "lighter" than just `bash` - it replaces your process with `bash` instead of spawning a child process with it. And using the here-string (the `<<<` construct) instead of `echo` and a pipe also save a sub process. If you prefer `echo` and a pipe, you can use `cmd2='"echo \"\$SSH_CONNECTION\" | awk '"'"'{ print \$1 }'"'"'; exec \$SHELL"'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with all the escaping problems, you could just access the variable in another way:

Just substitute `printenv SSH_CONNECTION` for `echo $SSH_CONNECTION`.  Notice that now there is no dollar sign, so the local shell will not expand the variable

Comment: You still have the quoting mess for the rest of the commands, notably awk to get the first part of the output of `SSH_CONNECTION`.

Comment: Dear future readers of this post. although I chose that other answer.. it should be noted that this answer.. probably has alot of intelligence behind it. because the "env" stuff is usually more "core" than those other things. if this answer also added awk or something to single out the ip from the 3 items that it prints.. it would have been the chosen answer by me.